# Как настроить code-style глобально для всех проектов?

Tags: c#, code-style, rider

Есть несколько C# проектов(solution-файлов), все они находятся в разных директориях, и относятся к одному продукту. В данный момент есть отдельный git-репозиторий, где хранятся настройки code-style, и в Rider на уровне глобального слоя подключаются эти настройки, соответственно уровень team-shared и personal сброшены, таким образом для всех проектов работает общий code-style. Но есть недостатки такого подхода, если кто-то со стороны захочет внести правки в код, у него не подключится автоматически наш code-style. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при скачивании проекта в IDE автоматически подключался code-style, и при этом была возможность настраивать его в одном месте? Т.е. можно добавлять .DotSettings в каждый проект, но тогда придется для каждого проекта отдельно вносить правки в code-style, что крайне неудобно.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8